# Need to add milliseconds to time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

### I have a data frame with some columns out of which one column is Time. I have calculated milliseconds from the data give to me and add that as a separate columns named as milliseconds. Now i concatenated both the columns to get a single column with milliseconds.

Problem is 
1.) I need milliseconds in three decimal place so I need to round that off. 
2.) When I am concatenating the time stamp with milliseconds so when seconds get increment with one the millisecond should start with zero again. Like after

In the below code 'sample' is constant = 60 and 'RDT Sequence' is value starting from one and increment by 1 for every next row.

```
2019-02-21 03:50:39:2
2019-02-21 03:50:40:216666666667
But instead I should get    
2019-02-21 03:50:40:00

Time    Miliseconds  \                    Time1  


0    2019-02-21 03:50:39  0166666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:39:0166666666667
1    2019-02-21 03:50:39  0333333333333   2019-02-21 03:50:39:0333333333333
2    2019-02-21 03:50:39             05   2019-02-21 03:50:39:05
3    2019-02-21 03:50:39  0666666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:39:0666666666667 
4    2019-02-21 03:50:39  0833333333333   2019-02-21 03:50:39:0833333333333 
5    2019-02-21 03:50:39              1   2019-02-21 03:50:39:1 
6    2019-02-21 03:50:39   116666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:39:116666666667
7    2019-02-21 03:50:39   133333333333   2019-02-21 03:50:39:133333333333
8    2019-02-21 03:50:39             15   2019-02-21 03:50:39:15
9    2019-02-21 03:50:39   166666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:39:166666666667
10   2019-02-21 03:50:39   183333333333   2019-02-21 03:50:39:183333333333
11   2019-02-21 03:50:39              2   2019-02-21 03:50:39:2
12   2019-02-21 03:50:40   216666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:40:216666666667
13   2019-02-21 03:50:40   233333333333   2019-02-21 03:50:40:233333333333
14   2019-02-21 03:50:40             25   2019-02-21 03:50:40:25
15   2019-02-21 03:50:40   266666666667   2019-02-21 03:50:40:266666666667

df['Miliseconds'] = df['RDT Sequence']/sample
df['Miliseconds'] = df['Miliseconds'].map(str).str[2:]
df['Time1'] = df['Time'].map(str) +":"+ df['Miliseconds'].map(str)  
print(df)
```

Comment: What are the dtypes of your dataframe?

Comment: maybe `pandas.TimeDelta` could help?

Comment: The Miliseconds columns make no sense to me. How is it generated and what does it represent exactly?

Comment: @Will I need to add milliseconds to the given time column. and Milliseconds will be calculated as I have mentioned above. So just to see that milliseconds I made one more column for that.

Comment: 133333333333 is a loooot of milliseconds

Comment: @will actually I was getting the answer like 0.0166666666667. But as I need to concatenate that with the seconds I striped down the first two digits so i got 0166666666667. Yes I need to round of to the 3 digts as well

Comment: got it. posting answer below

Comment: `df['Miliseconds'] = df['RDT Sequence']/sample` : how does this give numbers like "0666666666667"? How is that a float?

Comment: so If you see the value it gives 1/60 = 0.01666667 then I used str[2:] which removes the '0.' Then the example you asked it come from 4/60 as its in 4th row.

Comment: Ah, you posted the answer before the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Time" column is a string, you want a pandas Timestamp. 
Then you want milliseconds in a numeric format. Given that is in a format that represents the fractional part of a number we convert it to a fraction, round it off to 3 and then multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.
Lastly we use it to build a timedelta so it can be easily added to the Timestamp.

```
# The Miliseconds column is not currently in milliseconds, it is
# a fraction of a second (0.016)
# Rounding it off is easy
df["Miliseconds"] = df["Miliseconds"].round(3)
# Make it milliseconds, not fraction of a seconds
df["Miliseconds"] = df["Miliseconds"] * 1000

# Now add it to Time using a Timedelta
tdelta = pd.to_timedelta(df["Miliseconds"], unit="ms")
df["Time1"] = df["Time"] + tdelta
```

Many of the routines above can be done on a single line. I expanded here to illustrate each operation.

Comment: I try running the code till rounding of the milliseconds I am getting an error -> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects  @    df["Miliseconds"] = df["Miliseconds"].apply(lambda x: float("0." + x))

Comment: That's why I asked for the dtypes of the dataframe. So df["Miliseconds"] is  a float?

Comment: I just checked using print(df.Miliseconds.dtype) its giving float64

Comment: and dtype of Time column is datetime64[ns]

Comment: Updated the lambda. It simply takes Miliseconds, makes it a fraction.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0.0166666666667

Comment: I got this thing I just removed the "0." + from lambda

Comment: OK, your question and example data is mixing data types. I've edited answer again to assume df['Miliseconds'] is a number like 0.0166 which is actually in seconds (a fraction of a second)

Comment: I am really sorry for that @will But now I am getting the output

Comment: If you can help me with one more thing that would be really helpfull. If you see the data I am getting is 11   2019-02-21 15:50:39.200000  
12   2019-02-21 15:50:40.216670  If by something I can reset the miliseconds to 0 when the second increase from 39 to 40

Comment: That is a whole different class of question but doable. Is RDT Sequence a constant for the whole dataframe?

Comment: sample is constant = 60 but rdt sequence increses by one for every row so if you see row 11 which is 12th number so 12/60 is 0.2 and then 13/60 is 0.2166. Like this.

Comment: You just need to synchronize your sample generation to the second. How is sample generated? Can you not set the sample generator to 0 with your clock? Otherwise do a groupby on the seconds value of Time